# How can I center the bar graphs in a facet wrap and remove the x axis labels in the facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am seeking help with ggplot facetwraps to generate a figure where the bars are centered within each facet, and there are no labels on the x-axis on the facets (since they are labeled above).

How would you go about achieving this?

First, generate the data frame

```
act <- c("Wildlife viewing", "Wildlife viewing", "Wildlife viewing", 
         "Birdwatching", "Birdwatching", "Birdwatching", 
         "Wildlife photography", "Wildlife photography", "Wildlife photography", 
         "Deer hunting", "Deer hunting", "Deer hunting", 
         "Trapping", "Trapping", "Trapping", 
         "Fishing", "Fishing", "Fishing")

ppart <- c(65.87091, 60.64611, 66.12500,
           37.66578, 35.97651, 41.75000,
           29.00088, 26.28488, 30.50000, 
           53.40407, 28.92805, 42.37500, 
           9.018568, 3.524229, 5.250000, 
           63.21839, 44.19971, 57.62500)

Region <- c("UP", "SL", "NL", 
            "UP", "SL", "NL", 
            "UP", "SL", "NL",
            "UP", "SL", "NL",
            "UP", "SL", "NL",
            "UP", "SL", "NL")

df <- data.frame(act, ppart, Region) # create a df with % participation in various activities
```

Then, create the graphic.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = act, y = ppart, fill = Region)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~act) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2) +
    ylab("Percent participation in activity") + 
  xlab("") + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image: Resulting figure]

As you can see, when I use the above code to generate the graph, things are a bit smushed and there are obvious issues with spacing and labels. How can I resolve these?

Specifically, centering the bar graphs within each facet and removing the x-axis labels within facets. Please advise! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the canonical method is to use `scales = "free_x"` in  the facet, and to explicit remove the x-axis ticks with `breaks=NULL`.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = act, y = ppart, fill = Region)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~act, scales = "free_x") +   # changed
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2) +
    ylab("Percent participation in activity") + 
  xlab("") + 
    theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL)           # new
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great and a much better-looking graphic than what I would've produced. I am very rusty in ggplot and appreciate the help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = 0, y = ppart, fill = Region)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~act) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2) +
  ylab("Percent participation in activity") + 
  xlab("") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.